# Setting the mime-type for files stored in the private directory

Tags: html, drupal-7

How do I set the mime-type of files being served from the drupal private directory. I have a webm file in the private directory, and the I've added the `<video>` tag to the page using a *tpl* file.

I've tried adding

```
AddType video/webm .webm
```

to .htaccess. I've also tried installing the module "File Mime" to try to set the right mime type. I've tried adding

```
function mymodule_file_download($uri){
    return array('Content-type: '.'video/webm');
}
```

to my .module file. Nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out myself: I had to add the webm mimetype in the appropriate places in the `includes/files.mimetypes.inc` file to get drupal to serve private files with the correct mimetype.